# saving sensor data raspberry pi to data base

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working with raspberry pi and using DHT11 to read temperature and humidity values every second. I have to save these values into a database in real time.
here's my code that showing sensor data every second, i don't know how and where do i insert lines of connection to database.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime



# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# read data using pin 7
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=4)


while True:



    result = instance.read()
    if result.is_valid():
        print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
        #print("Temperature: %d F" % ((result.temperature * 9/5) + 32))
        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install MySQL db on your system then use PyMySQL or any other library for connection to MySQL from python if using PyMySQL go through this [DOC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_database_access.htm)

install library using

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

Make connection once so put connection codes on top your while loop

```
    db = PyMySQL.connect("localhost:port","username","password","database_name" )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    while True:
```

use cursor for SQL-QUERY execution inside while loop where you get valid results to be stored

```
sql = "insert into table_name(id,feild1,feild2) values (1,value1,value2);"    
# Execute the SQL command
cursor.execute(sql)
# Commit your changes in the database
db.commit()
```

change the fields table name and connection information as in database and replace values in INSERT statement to your sensor values